# Floating point cast results in arithmetic exception in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The following code is passed a 64 bit floating point (double) and reduces it to a 32 bit single before passing that value to an API.

```
  real*8 z
  real*4 z1
  z1 = real(z)
```

On some values of z we get an exception of;

> Received a SIGFPE: Arithmetic exception occurred

I've used a debugger to output the value in z and it turns out to be -1.1889755140229473e+044 so that's obviously the problem.

I thought `real(z)` would truncate this value to single precision though without an error. **How can I convert this 64 bit double to a 32 bit single without an exception?**

This is from an existing codebase that was previously compiled under Silverfrost Fortran 32 bit and is now gfortran 64 bit. Converting the whole call stack to single precision to work around it may not be possible.

Comment: Can you provide the specific problematic values of z?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format for the maximum 32-bit floating point value ( absolute value ≈ 3.402823e+38) and check the compiler documentation about handling floating point overflow.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl One value is noted above ( -1.1889755140229473e+044 ).

Comment: The cast itself just returns "Infinity" with gfortran (4, 5 and 7, 64-bit linux system)

Comment: @PierredeBuyl had the same problem but in message: "z and it turns out to be -1.1889755140229473e+044 "

Comment: With this value, I have a compile-time error `Error: Real constant overflows its kind at (1)`. When "computing this value" (I enter it with `d+34` then multiply by 10^10, just "Infinity"

Comment: Is the minimal example you provide actually erroring or is the error occuring later?

Comment: It's throwing the exception when assigning from z to z1.

Comment: What are the compiler flags?

Comment: No special flags, just '-fno-underscoring -fdollar-ok -ffixed-form -Wall '

Answer (score 2):

Posting as an answer, as I believe that I could identify the problem.

The behavior of gfortran for floating point exceptions depends on the flag `-ffpe-trap`. While you do not set it yourself, it might be enabled on your specific platform.

Using the following program

```
      real(kind=8) z
      real(kind=4) z1
      z = -1.1889755140229473d+034
      z = z*1d10
      z1 = real(z)
      write(*,*) z, z1
      end
```

I have the runtime exception when compiling with

```
 gfortran -ffpe-trap=overflow -o scast scast.f90
```

and the program just outputs

```
  -1.1889755140229473E+044        -Infinity
```

when I omit the flag `-ffpe-trap=overflow`.

To actually solve your problem, you must decide what to do when an overflow occurs. Unless you actually control the overflow behavior by some mechanism, 
the occurrence of the exception is a useful hint that there is a problem.

Finally, as Ian Bush mentions, you should take advantage of the current transition to also use standard-conforming declarations. See this [blog post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2017/03/27/doctor-fortran-in-it-takes-all-kinds) by Steve Lionel for a short intro to this issue.

Comment: Maybe use the module `iso_fortran_env` and replace `kind=8` by `kind=REAL64` and `kind=4` by `kind=REAL32`. The kind values are compiler dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming IEEE 32 and 64 bit reals the largest modulus numbers representable in single precision are around ±3.40282×10**38 . Your number is bigger than this, so converting to single precision will throw an exception.

Also please note real*8 and similar is not and never has been part of Fortran. Please learn about the Fortran kind mechanism.